# Swift ios hide button on certain screen sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I wonder how I can hide a button on certain screen sizes.
What I am trying to do is to show a button when the app is running on a iphone

Right now I have setup size classes, setting a width/height to 0 on a certain size class (ipads). This works, but is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating your button via code or interface builder?

Comment: @AdrianB Using interface builder, but I could do it with code as well

Comment: Via interface builder, you can configure the the layout based on the size class of the device. Here's where to look--> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableConstraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is actually to use size classes, as it is only dependant on the actual screen size. It would be bad if the size of the app is like an iPhone, but runs on an iPad in split view mode

Answer (score -2):

You can use `UIDevice.currentDevice().model`, which is equal to "iPhone" if the app is running on an iPhone or "iPad" if the app is running on an iPad.

Code snippet:

```
var model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
if model == "iPhone" {
thatbutton.hidden = false
} else {
thatbutton.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Nothing should be based on the device model. Everything should be done based on size. For example, an app running in multitasking mode on newer iPads. In such a case, the app's width will be much closer to that of an iPhone than a full iPad. And this answer will fail when run on an iPod touch.